# Habilitar o Deshabilitar 'Table' o cualquier otro Control a partir del cambio y seleccion de un DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspx

Tengo una duda, como puedo Habilitar o Deshabilitar una 'Tabla' al momento de seleccionar el value1 o value2 ?

Es decir, **si selecciono Value1 Muestro la tabla, en caso contrario al seleccionar el Value2.**

Este es mi DropDown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddownDesType" runat="server" css="input-form-edit" 
               CssClass="browser-default custom-select" runat="server"
               AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="false">
<asp:ListItem Value="-1">Seleccionar Tipo Desviacion</asp:ListItem>
```

Tengo entendido que hay una función '**OnSelectedIndexChanged**' propia del control de asp.net pero no se si esta es la manera correcta..

Desconozco si es que hay posiblidad con Javascript.

He estado intentando desde algunos eventos de los **Controles** pero no tengo exito aun.

Comment: Investigando pude hacer lo siguiente, mas no se si funcione, aun me falta hacer pruebas.


`Protected Sub ddownDesType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddownDesType.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ddownDesType.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
            DTAcciones.Visible = False
        ElseIf ddownDesType.SelectedValue.Any() Then
            DTAcciones.Visible = True
        Else
        End If

    End Sub`

Comment: Si con habilitar te refieres a esconder o mostrar la tabla, con javascript si que puedes hacerlo, si tienes incorporado JQuery a tu proyecto puedes usar el metodo `.change()` si es javascript puro puedes usar el atributo onchange y escribir una funcion que te oculte o muestre la tabla

Comment: @NicolasOñate Gracias por tu respuesta, y es correcto a eso me refiero, ocultar o mostrar ya que depende que de eso muestre otros controles (como algun input) o no. _Tendras algun ejemplo_ con el que me pueda dar alguna idea, la verdad es que soy nuevo en esto de Javascript, Frontend... 

He de ahí la razón del porque estoy usando el Selected Index Changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo por javascript usando el evento [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) puedes detectar tu dropdown por su id `ddownDesType` y obtener su value y dependiendo del valor ocultar o mostrar la tabla.

```js
document.getElementById("seleccion").onchange = function() {Mostrar(this.value)};

function Mostrar(val){
  var x = document.getElementById("tablaEjemplo");
  if (val === "1") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else if (val === "2"){
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
   x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id="tablaEjemplo" >
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dato1</td>
    <td>Dato2</td>
    <td>Dato3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<select id="seleccion">
  <option value="0">Seleccione un valor</option>
  <option value="1">Mostrar</option>
  <option value="2">Ocultar</option>
</select>
```

Esto se ejecutaria desde el lado cliente, desconozco el funcionamiento en VB pero añadiendo un EventHandler podrias lograrlo desde el lado del servidor

Comment: Wooow, te agradezco mucho.! ya vote tu respuesta pero aun tengo baja reputación ya que voy iniciando. Me haz ayudado mucho, prometo que me esforzare en aprender mas.

Comment: Si es correcta puedes marcarla con el tic de debajo de la votación, así pueden otros usuarios que tengan tu mismo problema ver facilmente la solución, aparte recibirás un poco de reputación